# sort records using string column by converting it to datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a string column in which I am storing a value like this "2015-11-04 09:09:00 PM". For a particular reason I have not considered it as a datetime column. Now I just want to order the records according to its ascending order. When I do a simple sort using order, I am not getting the expected output.

Help!

Comment: Try to elaborate your question. If you change its datatype to date and time then sorting will work.

Comment: No, but for a particular reason , I haven't considered it's datatype as datetime

Comment: I think then it will be difficult to do this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Model.all.sort_by{|m| m.field_name.to_datetime}
```